# Inherited class with different constructor

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to create an inherited class for some 3rd party code and I'm having trouble implementing it in the way I want to.

The code below is a rough guide for what I want to do.

```
// 3rd party class
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string Value1, string Value2)
    {
        // constructor does stuff with values
    }
    public string Method1()
    {
        // return value1
    }
    public string Method2()
    {
        // return value2
    }
}

// my class
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(string Key)
    {
        // decrypt key to get Value1 and Value2
        // create BaseClass(Value1, Value2)
    }
    public MyNewFunction(string Value)
    {
        // this is a function I've added, extending the base class
    }
}
```

There's a lot more going on than that example shows, but that is a basic example of the specific problem I'm facing.  The 3rd party code requires a LOT of setting up and I just want to wrap all that up in a simple constructor, but still be able to call the base classes public methods without having to write a wrapper for each of them.

Is there a sensible way to do this or am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: What's stopping you from calling the `BaseClass` constructor?

Comment: It complains about the subclass constructor not matching the base class constructor.  I need to be able to create an instance of the base class in the subclass constructor, despite the differences

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use a factory?

Comment: @flindeberg Other than having no idea what that is, no (assuming it would solve the problem).  Could you expand on that, maybe an example that would fix the above issue?

Comment: Please show the exact code that's causing the problem, we can't just guess for it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't have the 3rd party code - it's an assembly.  That's why I've explained the specific issue as a principle, rather than a "I get this error" type problem.

Comment: @Archer I've added an answer, does it make sense enough or should I expand on it more? But in general, try avoid calling constructors directly and use a creational pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do it like that, I would use a factory instead. The idea of the factory is to put the creation of objects a bit further from the user code, is if you ever need to change how a certain object is created you only have to have a look at the factory.

Also have a look at the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) . In general when creating objects try using a creational pattern, some can be found [at this link given the GoF creational patterns.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational) (Design Patterns by GoF (group of four) is one of the best reads with regards to object oriented patterns)

Like this:

```
public class BCFactory {
  public SubClass CreateInstance(string key)
  {
     var val1 = GetVal1FromKey(key);
     var val2 = GetVal2FromKey(key);
     // create the actual instance of the subclass
     var instance = new SubClass(val1, val2);

     return instance;
  }
}

public class SubClass {
   public SubClass(string val1, string val2) : base(val1, val2)
   {
      // Do nothing, we just instantiate the base class.
   }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var key = // your data
var factory = new BCFactory();
var instance = factory.CreateInstance(key);
```

Comment: This looks very promising - thanks.  I'll play for a few minutes and come back.

Comment: Actually, this will create an instance of the base class, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Archer, do so, the advantage of this is that you do not have to call the constructor explicitly, which can be cumbersome in the case of complex objects.

Comment: @Archer You have extended the base class?

Comment: Yes, I have - and will do a lot more in the future which is why I was attempting to use inheritance, rather than just write a function to create the object

Comment: @Archer Ah, that was not clear from the question, I thought your subclassing was just for creation, I'll edit and get back on that.

Comment: Okay thanks - sorry that wasn't clear.  I'll put something in the question to resolve that.

Comment: @Archer Changed the answer a bit, still I would recommend a factory method which does the heavy creational lifting, ie decrypting and playing around with your strings.

Comment: You've convinced me - I've gone down this route, thanks.  Just one question though.  Is there any reason for not making the factory class (and create method) static?  I've done it purely so that there's less code when creating an instance of the subclass, and I can't see any problem with it.

Comment: @Archer In this case no, but in case you need to extend it you might get into trouble, an example is the abstract factory pattern where you sometimes might need to create a `SubclassA` and sometimes a `SubclassB`, but if you are sure that kind of extension never is needed just go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `static` method call in your base-constructor call to manipulate the data. This example will show how:

```
void Main()
{
    new SubClass("somekey");
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string Value1, string Value2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (Value1 + "\t" + Value2);
    }
}
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(string Key) : base(Key, Decrypt(Key))
    {

    }

    static string Decrypt(string val){
        return val + "_decrypted";
    }
}
```

Which prints

> somekey  somekey_decrypted

Comment: The only problem I have with this is the parameters for the base constructor would need to each be a function call.  I guess that's not the end of the world but it does feel a little "scrappy".  The parameters in the base constructor are not what you have in this example, so it wouldn't work.

Comment: Please expand on your question. What do you mean with *the parameters for the base constructor would need to each be a function call*? Are you referring to `: base(Key, Decrypt(Key))`?

Comment: Yes - neither Value1 or Value2 (in the example) are the string passed into the constructor of SubClass.  To do what you've suggested here would require `:base(GetValue1(Key), GetValue2(Key));`

Comment: I'd hardly consider that a problem. Why is it these method calls are a considered scrappy?

Comment: Surely I'm not alone in thinking you shouldn't be running a decryption function multiple times to get multiple values?  You should run it once and get all the values.  I do see a way round it, and that is `:base(Decrypt(Key), Value2)` with the Decrypt function returning Value1 and setting a global Value2, but I'm still not fond of that.

Comment: Okay, now I'm following the question. Yes, in that case it definitely doesn't make sense. The [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is the one you're looking for (with the difference that you're not returning an abstracted value but a constant one). The answer you accepted is thus the correct one.

Comment: Thanks - I found this a difficult question to word, so much so that it's only half of my problem, but that's better than none.  Thanks for the help :)